# What if I don't want a question migrated to stackoverflow?

Tags: support, migration

There are times when questions migrate here from stackoverflow.  But do they migrate from here to over there too?  And if so, is it without my consent?

I don't want an account made automatically for me at SO, nor do I want my questions there.  I'd rather have the option of deleting/abandoning my question instead and going elsewhere.

Comment: An *account* won't be made for you automatically; you'll show up as an anonymous user with the same name I believe. The process of migration is not automatic; mods often don't migrate unless it's requested, but voters can vote to migrate it to one of a small set of other sites, including SO, and if there are enough votes (5) it gets migrated. Still, if you don't want to migrate, and the community votes to do it anyway, not much you can do. Your content is contributed to the site under Creative Commons license, so you can't really control its distribution once you post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes we do occasionally migrate programming specific questions from here to Stack Overflow. They have the better audience and skill set to answer programming questions.

It does happen without your consent if five people vote to migrate the question.

I don't know if this has a negative effect on your ability to ask question on the network though.

Comment: Just to supplement: questions get migrated only if the quality meets the standards of the target site, so questions off-topic here may simply be closed instead of migrating.  If it is migrated, it can get answered on the new site without your having an account there.  Your username from this site will appear as an unregistered user there.  I believe you can interact on your own thread as an unregistered user (comment to clairfy, accept an answer), so you can effectively get your question answered there without having an account.  You have the option to add an account there with one click.

Comment: BTW, any voting that occurs here prior to the transfer is transferred with the question and shows up on the target site as if it occurred there.  If you are interested in network-wide rep, I believe you may need to activate an account on the target site in order for the rep there to be added.  Not 100% sure on the last point.

Comment: I'm not interested in a network-wide rep, nor is a rep anywhere of any interest one way or the other to me.  I just don't want to have anything of mine vanish from one side and land in SO.  Apparently, I have no control over that.

Comment: I'm struggling to see what the problem is with having your programming question on a site for programmers?

Comment: Burgi, because you specifically asked, let's suffice it to say that I asked for my account to be removed there a long time ago, and when it didn't happen at first, I pushed hard for it.  I simply don't like the site any longer, nor what the folks there have largely morphed into.  But my reasons remain to the side of the reality that there isn't anything I can do about it, so the issue is largely closed.  I've attributed your response as "the" answer.

Answer (score 5):

If a question is a *programming* question it really does not belong here. We tend to discourage people from migrating questions that do belong here. And yes, SO is, and always has been a migration target for us.

As such, the ball is partially in your court. Don't ask questions that should be migrated to SO and it'll be fine. *Personally* I'd rather just close those. Amusingly, the only certain way to not get posts migrated to SO is... to be question banned there.

Other than that, the OP has no control over where something gets migrated to